# Añadir Jpanels y JButtons mediante un ciclo for

Tags: java-swing

Buenas amigos, tengo dificultades a la hora de añadir JPanels almacenados en un arrayList mediante un ciclo for, y a continuación ir añadiendo botones en el JPanel que corresponde al índice del arrayList en el que se encuentra, a continuación os paso el código a ver si me podéis echar una mano, el error en concreto es un nullpointerxception, gracias de antemano

//VISTA

```
public class testpanels extends JFrame{

private ArrayList <JPanel> panels;
private ArrayList <JButton> botones;

public testpanels(){

    super("pruebaPanels");

        panels = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){

        panels.add(new JPanel());
        panels.get(i).setLayout(new FlowLayout());

     }        
}

public ArrayList<JPanel> getPanels() {
    return panels;
}

public void setPanels(ArrayList<JPanel> panels) {
    this.panels = panels;
}

    public void bornButtons(String name){
    botones.add(new JButton(name));
}

public ArrayList <JButton> getBotones() {
    return botones;
}

public void setBotones(ArrayList <JButton> botones) {
    this.botones = botones;
}

}
```

//CONTROLADOR

```
public class controlador {

     testpanels vista = new testpanels();

    public controlador(){

    for(int i=0; i<=2;i++){ //crea 3 botones
            vista.bornButtons("TRY");
            vista.getPanels().get(0).add(vista.getBotones().get(0+i));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Editado]

No entiendo la razón de usar multiples panels, cuando no es necesario utilizar ninguno, únicamente el flow layout, intenta modificar el código de la siguiente forma a ver si cumple tus requerimientos (omití algunos métodos innecesarios):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class TestPanels extends JFrame {
    private ArrayList<JButton> botones;

    public TestPanels() {
        super();
        botones = new ArrayList<>();
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }

    public void bornButtons(String name) {
        JButton btn = new JButton(name);
        getContentPane().add(btn);
        botones.add(btn);

    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestPanels vista = new TestPanels();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) { //crea 3 botones
            vista.bornButtons("TRY " + i);
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                vista.pack();
                vista.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

El error del [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) se debe a que no inicializas el [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) de botones en tu constructor, únicamente haces

```
panels = new ArrayList<>();
```

Pero intentas agregar botones cuando llamas a

```
vista.bornButtons("TRY");
```

Modifica tu constructor así:

```
super("pruebaPanels");

panels = new ArrayList<>();
botones = new ArrayList<>(); //línea nueva

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    panels.add(new JPanel());
    panels.get(i).setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, solucione ese error estúpido, la cuestión, es que me muestra la ventana vacía, acabo de adentrarme en el modelo vista controlador, y se me escapan cosas, de todas maneras gracias de antemano